# How to draw text with line breaks using Python's PIL

Tags: python, string, python-imaging-library, line-breaks

I want to draw a string with multi-lines into an image. I'm using PIL for writing text into the image.

```
v = ''
for j in range(0,2):
    v += ("%s (%s%%)\n") % (career_list[j], ran_list[j])
txt2img(v)
```

But it's still displaying in one line. What am I doing wrong? (I want draw the string one time? Can we do it?)

Answer (score 1):

you concatenate *everything* into **v**. You should pull the drawing/printing function (txt2img(v)) in your loop.

```
for j in range(0,2):
    v = ("%s (%s%%)\n") % (career_list[j], ran_list[j])
    txt2img(v)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what i want is just draw one time. :)

Comment: @Chelsea_cole: Sometimes, you can't do exactly what you want; you have to do it the way that works with the software.

Answer (score 1):

There is no txt2img function in PIL. I used "Google" and it looks like you took the code from Koders.com. Anyway try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061165/python-imagedraw-text-writes-through-the-image-borders)